# where does the oldest log file get archived with python logging

Tags: python, logging

I have configured python logging with `RotatingFileHandler` with `backupCount` as 3 and `maxBytes` as 1024*1024 with base log file name as `test.log`.

What happens to `test.log.3` after it gets filled up. Does it get archived? If so, how do I find this location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RotatingFileHandler calls a [doRollover()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L154) method which checks `backupCount` then removes `test.log.3` with `os.remove()`.

The functionality of os.remove depends on your system. According to the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html), `os.remove()` will call the operating system's unlink functionality, and delete the file from the disk.

Likely, the filesystem probably just marks the sectors as free, and removes the file entry from the directory. It all depends on your OS / filesystem implementation.

Edit: For trying to find deleted files on linux you could try [debugfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files).

Answer (score 0):

[`backupCount`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) is the number of files, which are kept. Older files are being deleted.

When the `test.log` is filled, it's being renamed to the `test.log.1`.

Then `test.log.1` is being renamed to `test.log.2` and when it's reaches `test.log.3` it's being removed on the next rollover.